# Improve parsing speed for xmltodict

Tags: xmltodict

I have a compressed FIXML ZIP file. I am trying to use xmltodict to parse its uncompressed file (~130MB uncompressed data) as follows, but the parsing takes about 3 mins:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(ff, 'r') as fh:
     infile = fh.read(fh.namelist()[0])
o = xmltodict.parse(infile)
```

I have tried to use the latest version of xmltodict as well (0.9.0) since the release notes for a prior version outlines a peformance improvement, but this still didn't help...no speed improvement at all.

Any ideas on how this xmltodict parsing could be accomplished much faster?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure we can help here. it may be machine-dependent

Comment: I have tried this on 2 flavors of linux - ubuntu 10 (8 cores) and RHEL6 (24 cores) and same issue.

Comment: or any way to trace the bottleneck when the parsing is going on to rule out any system resource issue?

Comment: sounds like you're getting closers

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by closers. Could you please elaborate? Thanks.